# How to add CSS to head by php through echo self::css();

Tags: theme-customizer

The tutorial https://iamsteve.me/blog/hero-area-series-wordpress-customizer-with-selective-refresh#customizer-setup gives a method for changing color by WordPress Customizer (Color control). It changes the color through the following code

```
/**
 * For hooking into `wp_head` mostly to output CSS
 */
public static function output()
{
  echo '<style id="hero-css">';
  echo self::css('.hero', 'background-color', 'hero_background_color');
  echo '</style>';
}
```

When I do this, I get a 500 error. Am I missing something?

Edit: Right now I have a complete working `WP_Customize_Color_Control` and its `$wp_customize->add_setting` works with `refresh` right now, I want the transport to be `postMessage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial seems to create a whole class for working with css.

How about starting with a very basic example and working from there.

In order to add `<style>` to `<head>` you could hook into `wp_head` action.
Most theme uses it to load all styles, scripts etc., so you can be sure that you can hook into it.

A very basic example would look like this

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'bt_custom_head_style');
function bt_custom_head_style () {
?>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: hsl(200, 50%, 50%);
    }
</style>
<?php
}
```

This code goes into your `function.php`.